# React setState with arrays , how to auto create an array id without construct

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I'm trying to setState from firebase which respond from node and create  with google-maps-react like this

```js
{maskprop.map(({ ................. }, index) => (
          <Marker 
            onClick={this.onMarkerClick}
            name={name} 
            position={{lat, lng}} 
            key={index}
          />
))}
```

So i want to save the result in a state array.

The response data which i get from node:

```json
    {
    "2303240013": {
        "address": "臺中市西區民權路105號",
        "county": "臺中市",
        "location": {
            "lat": 120.675929,
            "lng": 24.141144
        },
        "mask_adult": 0,
        "mask_child": 0,
        "name": "臺中市中西區衛生所",
        "phone": "04 -22223811",
        "town": "西區",
        "updated": ""
    },
    "2317020010": {
        "address": "臺中市東區信義街142號",
        "county": "臺中市",
        "location": {
            "lat": 120.687798,
            "lng": 24.13337
        },
        "mask_adult": 0,
        "mask_child": 0,
        "name": "臺中市東區衛生所",
        "phone": "04 -22834121",
        "town": "東區",
        "updated": ""
    }
}
```

and i want to setState like below

```json
    0:
    address: "address1"
    county: "county1"
    location: {lat: 120.888455, lng: 24.173788}
    mask_adult: 0
    mask_child: 100
    name: "name1"
    phone: "phone1"
    town: "town1"
    updated: "2020/02/14 22:59:03"
    1:
    address: "address2"
    county: "county2"
    location: {lat: 120.888455, lng: 24.173788}
    mask_adult: 0
    mask_child: 100
    name: "name2"
    phone: "phone2"
    town: "town2"
    updated: "2020/02/14 22:59:03"
```

This is my code now, it can only get the last state which i set for `maskprop`.
Can someone introduce the way to create index for the arrays?

```js
async getfirebasedata(){
    const response = await axios.post(
      'http://127.0.0.1:9000/hello',
      { county: '臺中市' },
      { headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' } }
    )
    //console.log(response.data);
    var getdata = response.data;
    var item;
    for(item in getdata){
      //console.log(getdata[item].address);
      this.setState({
        maskprop:[
        {
          address: getdata[item].address,
          county: getdata[item].county,
          location: getdata[item].location,
          mask_adult: getdata[item].mask_adult,
          mask_child: getdata[item].mask_child,
          name: getdata[item].name,
          phone: getdata[item].phone,
          town: getdata[item].town,
          updated: getdata[item].updated,
        }],
      })
    }

    console.log(this.state.maskprop);
  }
```

Or any other ways to create multiple  ?

Comment: Instead of doing `setState` inside for loop, first create your array inside for loop and once the loop is completed, do the `setState`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [Object.keys](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) and [.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) to convert the object to array,

```js
const data = {
    "2303240013": {
        "address": "臺中市西區民權路105號",
        "county": "臺中市",
        "location": {
            "lat": 120.675929,
            "lng": 24.141144
        },
        "mask_adult": 0,
        "mask_child": 0,
        "name": "臺中市中西區衛生所",
        "phone": "04 -22223811",
        "town": "西區",
        "updated": ""
    },
    "2317020010": {
        "address": "臺中市東區信義街142號",
        "county": "臺中市",
        "location": {
            "lat": 120.687798,
            "lng": 24.13337
        },
        "mask_adult": 0,
        "mask_child": 0,
        "name": "臺中市東區衛生所",
        "phone": "04 -22834121",
        "town": "東區",
        "updated": ""
    }
}

const array = Object.keys(data).map(key => data[key]);

console.log(array)
```

```
async getfirebasedata() {
  const response = await axios.post(
    "http://127.0.0.1:9000/hello",
    { county: "臺中市" },
    { headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" } }
  );
  //console.log(response.data);
  const getData = response.data;
  const data = Object.keys(getData).map(key => getData[key]);

  this.setState({
    maskprop: data
  }, () => console.log(this.state.maskprop));
}
```

Comment: i'm getting six thousand results from firebase, can you explain the way to const the data in? thanks

Comment: @ChenJohnny I've updated ```getFirebaseData``` function.

Comment: Thanks for helping! but I got this error : Unhandled Rejection (ReferenceError): Cannot access 'data' before initialization.

Comment: change data to getData

Comment: this error cause of this line 'const data = Object.key(getData).......' I don't know what you mean of change data to getData...

Comment: ```const data = Object.keys(getData).map(key => getData[key]);```

Answer (score 0):

Just iterate through an object and turn in into an array, but I should notice that object is not a flat structure, so index will be created in arbitrary sequence.

```js
const apiData = {
    "2303240013": {
        "address": "臺中市西區民權路105號",
        "county": "臺中市",
        "location": {
            "lat": 120.675929,
            "lng": 24.141144
        },
        "mask_adult": 0,
        "mask_child": 0,
        "name": "臺中市中西區衛生所",
        "phone": "04 -22223811",
        "town": "西區",
        "updated": ""
    },
    "2317020010": {
        "address": "臺中市東區信義街142號",
        "county": "臺中市",
        "location": {
            "lat": 120.687798,
            "lng": 24.13337
        },
        "mask_adult": 0,
        "mask_child": 0,
        "name": "臺中市東區衛生所",
        "phone": "04 -22834121",
        "town": "東區",
        "updated": ""
    }
}

const parseApiData = data => {
  return Object.keys(data).map(key => data[key])
}

console.log(parseApiData(apiData))
```

Comment: i'm getting six thousand results from firebase, can you explain the way to const the data in? thanks

Comment: I don't really get "const the data in" part, but in your case, when data arrives you should to call `parseApiData` function that returns array of data you need, then you can perform `this.setState` and use as you want